# Unable to judge

Tags: jupyter

I hope that when I press enter, Can judge whether there is "好" or "玩啊" or "GO" or "要",If not, it will be executed "Game termination!"

```
%pylab inline
start = input("玩猜數字遊戲嗎?")
if start in "好" or "玩啊" or "GO" or "要":
    print("遊戲開始`enter code here`,已從0-100產生一個數字")
    print("您有3次錯誤的機會")
    a = randint(0, 101)
    print(a)
    for i in range(3):
        s = input("請輸入一個數字")
        s = float(s)
        if s == a:
            print("恭喜你答對了!!!!!!!!")
            break
        else:
            print("答錯了，已使用{}條命".format(i+1))
            i = i+1
            while i ==3:
                print("遊戲結束Game Over")
                break
else:
    print("Game termination!")
```

But I found that as long as there is the same as [start = input("玩猜數字遊戲嗎?")] , If you can’t judge, you will execute if,not else

Comment: don't post an image of your code. Just copy it into your question as text.

Comment: ok,sorry!!!!!!!

Comment: did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
if start in ["好", "玩啊", "GO", "要"]:
```

just put all the items to be compared inside a list.